# Movement axis have disappeared

Tags: interface

In one of my projects I have somehow managed to disable the axis that show up when moving an object. Where is the option to reenable this?
[image]

Comment: The same happened to me, I hit the play Animation shortcut accidentally.
.

Answer (score 4):

In Object Mode, these gizmos can be enabled/disabled from the drop down menu on the second button in the top right corner of the view under Object Gizmos (see screenshot).

[image]

Here is a great video all about these gizmos with more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6KyaVQ6Tgs

Answer (score 2):

Hi dan that axis gizmo shows up when the moving tool is enabled you can get it back by just going to the toolbar on the (corner of your the blender window) and selecting the 3rd tool

[image]

If that doesn`t work then try going up to the ***'show gizmo'*** option and make sure that the ***'move'*** option is enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How do I get my axis back in Blender?

I found this to be a better answer for me.

1. Select the two overlapping spheres icon (the overlay menu)
2. Check the Floor button and click on X Y Z buttons.

Answer (score -1):

like this press the show gizmo icon it turns blue to grey then axis wont show,< the bow and arrow icon > ,[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).